# Angular: Performance implication of using object literals in component template for ng-template context with ngTemplateOutlet

Tags: angular, angular-template

What are the performance implications of using an object literal in the template when passing context to ng-template?

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="template;context:{ field: value };"></ng-container>
```

as opposed to:

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="template;context:context;"></ng-container>

context = { field: value }
```

Is change detection going to run more often in the first case, since it's (presumably) creating a new object?

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/c2868de25a0fe4e14e4da4aae6aa2d5867711d05/packages/common/src/directives/ng_template_outlet.ts

```
  /**
   * We need to re-create existing embedded view if:
   * - templateRef has changed
   * - context has changes
   *
   * We mark context object as changed when the corresponding object
   * shape changes (new properties are added or existing properties are removed).
   * In other words we consider context with the same properties as "the same" even
   * if object reference changes (see https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13407).
   */
  private _shouldRecreateView(changes: SimpleChanges): boolean {
    const ctxChange = changes['ngTemplateOutletContext'];
    return !!changes['ngTemplateOutlet'] || (ctxChange && this._hasContextShapeChanged(ctxChange));
  }
```

Judging by this I would say it does make a difference because the function call is more expensive if `"ngTemplateOutletContext"` is in `changes`. And it always would be there if it's defined as an object literal in the template. This assumes that a new object is created every cycle. Is this assumption wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stumbled against this [article](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3109-inline-object-literals-dont-trigger-unnecessary-input-changes-in-angular-2-rc-2.htm) explaining that a literal object in templates doesn't imply a new instance on every detect cycle. I [checked it out](https://stackblitz.com/edit/literal-in-template?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) with a modern versions of Angular and its behavior is the same. So, I suppose that construction like in your code snippet is okay and it can be used without any problem.